# How to establish a connection between 2 folders in different workspaces in Control-M?

Tags: dependencies, workspace, control-m

I have 2 folders in 2 workspaces - say Folder_A and Folder_B - each with 3 jobs inside them.
Job_1 in Folder_A orders Folder_B to run. Upon Folder_B's run completion, Job_2 in Folder_A should run. Is there a way to achieve this without having to bring both folders in the same workspace?

I tried adding Out conditions (Actions) in Folder_B and In conditions (Prerequisite) in Job_2 Folder_A. Folder_A is stuck in waiting process even after Folder_B completed it's run